# Differentiating a Log Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

My current $\ln$ function is:
$$
\ln\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big) = b_1 + b_2 ln(x).
$$

How would I find the elasticity for this model?

What I have done so far is convert the equation to:
$$
\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big) = e^{b_1 + b_2 \ln(x)}
$$

Comment: What is elasticity given by?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to evaluate the elasticity. First you can use the definition

$$\boxed{\mathcal E=\frac{d y}{d x}\cdot \frac{x}{y}}$$

\begin{align*} 
& 
\ln\frac{y}{x}=\ln y-\ln x=b_1+b_2\cdot \ln x \\& \ln y=b_1+\ln x(b_2+1) \\& y=e^{b_1+\ln x(b_2+1)}=e^{b_1}\cdot x^{b_2+1} \\& \frac{d y}{d x}=(b_2+1)\cdot e^{b_1}\cdot x^{b_2} \\  
\end{align*}

Therefore

$$\mathcal E=\frac{d y}{d x}\cdot \frac{x}{y}=(b_2+1)\cdot e^{b_1}\cdot x^{b_2}\cdot\frac{x}{e^{b_1}\cdot x^{b_2+1}}=(b_2+1)\cdot \frac{e^{b_1}\cdot x^{b_2+1}}{e^{b_1}\cdot x^{b_2+1}}=b_2+1$$

Or you use the much simpler definition in this case:

$$\boxed{\mathcal E=\frac{d \ \ln y}{d \ \ln x }}$$

We have $\ln y=b_1+\ln x(b_2+1)$. Differentiating $\ln y$ w.r.t $\ln x$ is quite simple.